# Magento call custom php code through jquery ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, magento-1.8

Hi I am new to magento I am trying to achieve to call simple custom php through jquery ajax from the frontend. I have searched in the google they have given the answer to create a custom module then you can call the php through jquery ajax. I have tried the steps below are the following steps I have tried please check it and let me know what is my mistake

```
<script>
                        var jq = jQuery.noConflict();
                        jq(document).ready(function(){
                            jq(".listing_duplicate" ).on( "click", function() {
                                var id= this.id;
                            var uniqu_number = id.split("_");

                            var unique  = uniqu_number[3];

jq.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "JSON",
            data :{'value':unique},
            url :"<?php echo $this->getUrl('customajax/ajax/index'); ?>",
            success:function(data){
                alert(data);

              }
        });
         });
          });
</script>
```

Above is the phtml file where I call the ajax

I have created custom module in the below path 
I have created `xxx.com\app\code\local\Custom\Customajax\etc\config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <ThomasRyan_Checkoutajax>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </ThomasRyan_Checkoutajax>
  </modules>
  <frontend>
  <routers>
          <customajax>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
              <module>Custom_Customajax</module>
              <frontName>customajax</frontName>
            </args>
          </customajax>
       </routers>

    <layout>
     <updates>
       <checkoutajax>
         <file>checkoutajax.xml</file>
       </checkoutajax>
     </updates>
   </layout>
 </frontend>
</config>
```

In this path I have created the controller `xxx.com\app\code\local\Custom\Customajax\controllers\AjaxController.php`

```
<?php

class ThomasRyan_Checkoutajax_AjaxController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {

     public function indexAction() {
        echo 'Hello Index!';
    }
}
```

In this path I have created the block `xxx.com\app\code\local\Custom\Customajax\block\Customajax.php`

```
<?php
class Custom_Customajax_Block_Customajax extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
    echo "teswtme";
}
?>
```

And finally to activate the module I have added `xxx.com\app\etc\config.xml`

```
<blocks>
        <custom_customajax>
            <class>Custom_Customajax_Block</class>
        </custom_customajax>
    </blocks>
```

xxx.com\app\etc\modules\ThomasRyan_Checkoutajax.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
     <ThomasRyan_Checkoutajax>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
        </ThomasRyan_Checkoutajax>
    </modules>
</config>
```

Please tell me where I have made mistake while calling the jquery ajax for me its showing this error not found why is it showing what is the mistake below is my error.

`POST http://localhost/xxx.com/index.php/customajax/ajax/index/ 404 (Not` Found)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have created folders like Custom > Yourmodule > files and in config and everywhere else you have defined it as **ThomasRyan_Checkoutajax** this is where you are going wrong. it should be **Custom_Checkoutajax** like your code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
 <ThomasRyan_Checkoutajax>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
    </ThomasRyan_Checkoutajax>
    </modules>
</config>
```

which should be

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
 <modules>
   <Custom_Checkoutajax>
        <active>true</active>
        <codePool>local</codePool>
    </Custom_Checkoutajax>
 </modules>
</config>
```

Comment: Okay my question where are the places should I want to change the name custom_checkout ajax?

Comment: I mentioned that already.. replace ThomasRyan_Checkoutajax with Custom_Checkoutajax in all your plugin files. I have editted my answer check.